# Known conflicts between use of HC-12 and Ethernet Shield on Mega2560?

Tags: arduino-mega, ethernet-shield, hc-12

I have two somewhat similar sketches that use both HC-12 [for data collection] and a W5100-type Ethernet Shield [for Email construction and transmit].
Both sketches run fine until the code for the Ethernet Shield is invoked, which creates a connection and successfully transmits an Email.
Once this happens, the HC-12 no longer receives transmits.  No exceptions are raised, and I am at a loss to determine the cause of the problem.
[The HC-12 is using pins 50-52.]

I have other sketches that use either the HC-12 or the Ethernet Shield, and they work fine.  Before I build a custom sketch to attempt problem isolation,
I thought I would simply ask the question of whether known conflicts exist.  I know that many questions are resolved by posting the sketch and someone other
than the author scanning it.  I think that impractical in this particular case.  The sketch comprises 6,000+ lines of code.

If no helpful responses are forthcoming, I will continue with problem isolation, and post again if no success is achieved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unanswerable without further details, especially which pins the Ethernet shield is using and the interaction between the software attempting to use each.  For that matter, it's bad form to mention something obscure like the HC12 and not explain what it is *and what the utilized pins do*.

Comment: Are you using SoftwareSerial on GPIO pins instead of using one of the three hardware UART ports?

Comment: @Majenko I am using SoftwareSerial simply because I started on an Uno, and didn't/don't know any better.   Bad idea, I guess? I've little experience with Mega2560, and none with the hardware UART ports.
I selected pins 50-52 for the HC-12, because I thought they were free, as the Ethernet shield plugs into pins 10-13.  However, my recent reading implies that the Ethernet code references 50-53 anyway, though I don't understand how.  If so, this certainly would be a source of conflict.  Perhaps this is the point you are leading up to?

In any case, i think I now have an avenue to pursue.

Comment: I have a feeling (though I am not sure, I'd have to check) you happened to pick the SPI pins which the Ethernet shield uses (through the ICSP header). Never use SoftwareSerial unless you absolutely have to (and you don't - you have Serial1, Serial2, etc available).

Comment: One thing I know for sure about the HC-12 is that you need to have an external power supply capable of giving it about 200 mA just for it.  Plus another 350 for the board, and some more for the shield.  I suspect the shield being activated is making the current drop below what the HC-12 needs to operate.  Can you give it a better power supply then come back and give us an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Majenko, the problem results from using Software Serial for the HC-12, and unfortunately choosing the pin set 50-52, which conflicts with the pin usage specification for the Ethercard Library.
Hence, the HC-12 code works fine until usage of the Ethernet shield is finally activated.  From that point on, the Ethernet code functions properly,  whilst the HC-12 code does not.  The recommended solution, which does indeed solve the problem, is to abandon usage of SoftwareSerial for the HC-12, and use Serial1, or Serial2, or Serial3 instead.

I do not feel that the solution to the problem is truly mine, but post it only that the information may be of subsequent use to a user encountering a problem of similar nature.